# Notification for Read Access for a Cloud Storage File

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am serving a file through Google Cloud Storage. If an user access it, is it possible to get a notification?

I have check [Cloud Pub/Sub Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). This deals about object created or delete inside a bucket.

I am looking for read access for a file. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for real-time notifications on object reads. You can, however, enable [hourly access logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) that you can scan over to see who's been reading your files recently, and you can get notifications when those access logs are available.

Comment: I think this is the only solution available for now.